# Terraform variable to assign using function

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
variable "cidr" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
      development = "x.1.0.0/16"
      qa = "x.1.0.0/16"
      default = "x.1.0.0/16"
  }
}
```

```
variable "network_address_space" {
  default = lookup(var.cidr, var.environment_name,"default")
}
```

Am getting error that "Error: Function calls not allowed"

```
variable "subnet_address_space": cidr_subnet2_address_space = cidrsubnet(var.network_address_space,8,1)
```

Comment: You can't use interpolation or function calls in variables. Use a [`local`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) instead.

Comment: oh, sad to hear that. Is it because of dynamical ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in [Interpolate variables inside .tfvars to define another variable](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17229) by the Hashicorp person, it is intended to be constant by design.

> Input variables are constant values passed into the root module, and so they cannot contain interpolations or other expressions that do not yield a constant value.

We cannot use variables in backend either as in [Using variables in terraform backend config block](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13022).

These are the things we Terraform users tripped on at some point, I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

A Terraform [Input Variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) is analogous to a function argument in a general-purpose programming language: its value comes from an expression in the calling module, not from the current module.

The `default` mechanism allows us to substitute a value for when the caller doesn't specify one, but because variables are intended for getting data into a module from the outside, it doesn't make sense to set the default to something from *inside* that module: that would cause the result to potentially be something the caller of the module could never actually specify, because they don't have access to the necessary data.

Terraform has another concept [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) which are roughly analogous to a local variable within a function in a general-purpose programming language. These *can* draw from function results and other objects in the current module to produce their value, and so we can use input variables and local values together to provide fallback behaviors like you've illustrated in your question:

```
var "environment_name" {
  type = string
}

var "environment_default_cidr_blocks" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
      development = "10.1.0.0/16"
      qa          = "10.2.0.0/16"
  }
}

var "override_network_range" {
  type    = string
  default = null   # If not set by caller, will be null
}

locals {
  subnet_cidr_block = (
    var.override_network_range != null ?
    var.override_network_range :
    var.environment_default_cidr_blocks[var.environment_name]
  )
}
```

Elsewhere in the module you can use `local.subnet_cidr_block` to refer to the final CIDR block selection, regardless of whether it was set explicitly by the caller or by lookup into the table of defaults.

When a module uses computation to make a decision like this, it is sometimes useful for the module to export its result as an [Output Value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) so that the calling module can make use of it too, similar to how Terraform resources also export additional attributes recording decisions made by the provider or by the remote API:

```
output "subnet_cidr_block" {
  value = local.subnet_cidr_block
}
```

Comment: Note that items in the "locals" block are referred to as "local." This is correctly show in this example. Thanks Martin.